# Extracting values from JSONB in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table (users) in which I store different columns, one of them being a **jsonb** column named content. The other columns don't matter because they refer to date and other non-related stuff. In that jsonb column we store a file that has the following syntax:

```
{
 "Root": {
    "Users": {
        "user1": {
            "Email": {
                "_value": "user1@email.com"
            },
            "FullName": {
                "_value": "User1"
            },
            "Teams": {
                "_value": "TeamA, TeamB"
            },
        "user2": {
            "Email": {
                "_value": "user2@email.com"
            },
            "FullName": {
                "_value": "User2"
            },
            "Teams": {
                "_value": "TeamA, TeamB, TeamC"
            }, 
....
```

What I am trying to achieve: extract all users from this jsonb and each parameter in a table that should look like this:

```
username |      email    |  fullname   |   teams
user1    |user1@email.com|  User1      | TeamA, TeamB
user2    |user2@email.com|  User2      | TeamA, TeamB, TeamC
```

I tried using **jsonb_object_keys**(content->'Root'->'users') and managed to extract all the users but can't seem to go forward in the tree to extract each value for each user. I am blocked and can't seem to find anything that suits me. The final goal would be extracting every user with said details based on a Team parameter I provide, so I will be putting everything in a function. I inherited this structure and in the same time I am a newbie in using jsonb general. 
Even something that can flatten in some way this jsonb would be great.

PostgreSQL version used: 9.5

If anyone has some input it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`teams` is a homework, the rest is sampled below:

```
t=# with o as (with j as (select '
{
 "Root": {
    "Users": {
        "user1": {
            "Email": {
                "_value": "user1@email.com"
            },
            "FullName": {
                "_value": "User1"
            },
            "Teams": {
                "_value": "TeamA, TeamB"
            }
        },
        "user2": {
            "Email": {
                "_value": "user2@email.com"
            },
            "FullName": {
                "_value": "User2"
            },
            "Teams": {
                "_value": "TeamA, TeamB, TeamC"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}'::jsonb v)
select key,value from j join jsonb_each(j.v->'Root'->'Users') on true) select key username, value->'Email'->>'_value' email, value->'FullName'->>'_value' fullname from o;
 username |      email      | fullname
----------+-----------------+----------
 user1    | user1@email.com | User1
 user2    | user2@email.com | User2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Will test tomorrow and then will accept as answer. One question only, what do you mean by **teams** is a homework? I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: I did not include last column - leaving it for you to do